# How to rebuild keras model from weights that are saved in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, keras, model, load

I am training a keras model and saving the weights into a JSON file like so:

```
with open('weigths.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(model.get_weigths())
```

Now I want to load the weights and rebuild the keras model so that I can do testing and prediction

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To save a model, you should use the dedicated function `keras.model.save(filepath)` and load it again with `keras.models.load_model(filepath)` as explained [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

Comment: It's because I want to save other information alongside the weights so I choose a json format that will help me do that